# Set the owner of documentum ACL in java using the API?

Tags: java, acl, documentum, dfc

I am doing a java project connected to Documentum data storage . I am trying to create an ACL manually using the API class . The following is my code :

```
            StringBuilder newAcl = new StringBuilder();
            newAcl.append(selectedItem.getName());
            newAcl.append(selectedItem.getId());
            newAcl.append("_acl");
            IDfACL acl = (IDfACL)_session.newObject("dm_acl");

            acl.setObjectName(newAcl.toString());
            acl.setDescription(newAcl.toString());

            acl.save();

            IDfPermit permit = new DfPermit();

            permit.setAccessorName(newAcl.toString());
            permit.setPermitType(IDfPermit.DF_ACCESS_PERMIT);
            permit.setPermitValue(IDfACL.DF_XPERMIT_CHANGE_FOLDER_LINKS_STR);
            permit.setPermitValue(IDfACL.DF_PERMIT_READ_STR);
            acl.grantPermit(permit);

            acl.save();
```

The thing is I can successully create the ACL I'm trying to create and it's retrievable  from dm_acl table object . The only thing that I've stucked at is how to set the owner as I have never specified that in my code and once I check the dm_acl table it says that the owner is dm_admin . Any idea how can I fix that ? Beside although I can create the ACL successfully in dm_acl but I get an error as well saying :

> [DM_ACL_E_USER_NOT_EXIST]error:  "The owner_name or accessor_name
>   'China InvestmentsCIL_acl' given in the ACL 'China InvestmentsCIL_acl'
>   does not exist."

Comment: I assume that ACL owner is indirectly set from the session owner that creates dm_acl object. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Try this:

acl.setString("owner_name", "dm_dbo");
acl.save();

Comment: @KarolBe Thanks Worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `[DM_ACL_E_USER_NOT_EXIST]` error you are facing is probably because in some point of time you had that owner / group when you created your ACL and in meanwhile somehow it was deleted. Now when you are updating your `dm_acl` object you are facing this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code you are not defining ACL accessor correctly. From the message you can see that 
**you are tying to set the name of the ACL as a the name of the accessor.**

`permit.setAccessorName(newAcl.toString());`

And it should be the name of an existing user/group for which you are setting permissions.